# TikZ double arrow between table rows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, arrows

I need to create a double curved arrow that connects two cells in my table. I have found some sample a got this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][-3pt]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.5ex]\node[#1](#2){};}


\newcounter{arrow}
\setcounter{arrow}{0}
\newcommand{\drawcurvedarrow}[3][]{%
\refstepcounter{arrow}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[double] (#2.center)edge[#1]node[coordinate,pos=0.5, name=arrow-\thearrow]{}(#3.center);
}

% #1 options, #2 position, #3 text 
\newcommand{\annote}[3][]{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[#1] at (#2) {#3};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Discrete Time} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Continuous Time} \\
\hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{12}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Stochastic system}}} &  &\\
&$x_{n+1}=f(x_n,u_n)+W_n{,} \hspace{10 mm} \textrm{ initial condition: } x_0$&\\
&&\\
& $W_n = P(\cdot \mid x_n,u_n)$ &\\
& &\\
& Cost function: &\\
& $\min\limits_{u_{0 \to t_f}} E \{ \Phi(t_f)+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{t_f -1} \alpha L(x_k,u_k)  \} \hspace{10mm} \alpha \in [0,1]$ &\\
&&\\
& Bellman equation: &\\
& $V^*(n,x)= \min\limits_{u_n} \{L(x_n,u_n)+ \alpha E[V^*(n+1,x_{n+1})] \}$ &\\
&$V^*(t_f,x_{t_f})=\Phi(t_f)$&\\
&  &\\
& Infinite horizon: \hspace{10 mm}  $\alpha \in [0,1]$&\\
& $\Phi(t_f)=0 \hspace{10mm}$V is NOT function of time.\tikzmark[xshift=2em]{a}&\\
& text &\\
\hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Deterministic system}}} &  &\\
&  \tikzmark[xshift=3.5em]{b} $x_{n+1}=f(x_n,u_n){,} \hspace{10 mm} \textrm{ initial condition: } x_0$\tikzmark[xshift=1.5em]{b}&\\
&&\\
& Cost function: &\\
& $\min\limits_{u_{0 \to t_f}} \{ \Phi(t_f)+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{t_f -1} \alpha L(x_k,u_k)  \} \hspace{10mm} \alpha \in [0,1]$ &\\
&  &\\
&  Bellman equation: &\\
& $V^*(n,x)= \min\limits_{u_n} \{L(x_n,u_n)+ \alpha V^*(n+1,x_{n+1}) \}$ &\\
& text &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend left=60,-stealth]{a}{b}
\annote[right]{arrow-1}{Duplicate}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I cannot figure out how I can change the arrow style to double arrow (`\Rightarrow`).

Comment: It is quite easy: try to add a `double` option to the path. For example:`\drawcurvedarrow[bend left=60,-stealth,double]{a}{b}`. Customization is available with: `\drawcurvedarrow[bend left=60,-stealth,double distance=2pt]{a}{b}` (select the dimension fits more your needs).

Comment: Tanks a lot for helping!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino an answer/

Comment: @cmhughes: I thought there was already something on this, but questions I found are not adequate to consider this as a duplicate. That's why I didn't answered immediately.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite easy: try to add the option `double` to the path. For example:

```
\drawcurvedarrow[bend left=60,-stealth,double]{a}{b}.
```

Customization is available with the option `double distance=<dim>`:

```
\drawcurvedarrow[bend left=60,-stealth,double distance=2pt]{a}{b}
```

(select the dimension fits more your needs).

Comment: Why community wiki?